Using "might" in past tense
I'm aware that "may" is generally present tense and "might" is generally past tense, but I came across a sentence in my writing that made me think I might have switched to present tense accidentally.

She said she loved him. That might be even less likely than everything else.

I'm aware I could change it to "That might have been," but I don't like the way it distances it. I simplified the sentences significantly to not directly put my writing out there, but I very much want the reader to feel the impossibility of her loving him.
Once I found this, I did some looking and found no end to examples of this kind of sentence from big publishing houses. An example I have still open is from Stephen King's Under the Dome.

No matter how beautiful this particular day, winter was lurking a page or two over on the calendar. The south might be good. He'd never been to Muscle Shoals...

This is far from the only example in this book (it's from the 11th page), much less his other writing or that of other authors.
I believe part of my problem is, when I read the sentence by itself, it is something I could see myself or anyone else saying aloud in present tense.
I've been looking around for an explanation of what's going on here (it's so ubiquitous I feel I have to be misunderstanding something or just really stupid) but can't find anything. I see people discussing "may vs. might", but it seems people mostly focus on archaic uses and formality, and that's not helping.
I've also seen people talking about indirect speech--I even used it in the start of this question with "I think I might have switched"--but that isn't answering me either.
I certainly wouldn't write "That may be even less..." when sticking to past tense as it's clearly present tense, but I'm having trouble convincing myself "That might be even less..." is past tense. I'm thinking it could be acceptable as either present or past tense depending on context...
Am I going crazy? Someone please help

I think this might be a better question for Literature. I think your examples are fine. But they aren’t about grammar. They’re about style and point of view — you have narration within narration... No matter how beautiful this particular day, winter was lurking a page or two over on the calendar. The south might be good, [he thought]. He’d never been to Muscle Shoals...

I would have added have been: "That might have been even less likely."

Why get so fixated on using might in the first place, if it's gonna raise all these doubts? Just rephrase: She said she loved him, which was perhaps even less likely than everything else.

It's really about might be vs might have been rather than may vs might. My intuition is that might have been is the past tense and may be is the present tense - same as in lots of other situations where you need to change the tense of both verbs. ("He says he is" vs "He said he was").
